# How to make an automatic substitution of an ID from a database in a dataGridView for a new record?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I am using SQL Server, and have an `ID` (auto-increment) for new records in SQL Server.
 
Feature: the code adds the current value of the autoincrement, and not maximum, which is used in the table.

In other words: the maximum value of the `ID` column is "3", the current value of the auto increment is equal to 5, because the entries with `ID = "4"` and "5" were deleted. Therefore the `ID` of the new record will be equal to "6".

[image]

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_01_Groups] 
(
    [id_group] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nameGroup] NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Property_1_Group] NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Property_2_Group] NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Property_3_Group] NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_01_Groups_2] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([id_group])
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

My code for working with the database:

```
public DataTable CreateCmds_2()
{
    table_2 = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=Prb;Integrated Security=True";

        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_01_Groups";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        // adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(true); //Добавил
        cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        connection.Open();
        adapter.Fill(table_2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
        string t = ex.StackTrace;
        // throw;
    }

    return table_2;
}

public void Save_1()
{
    try
    {
        // adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        adapter.Update(table_2);
        //adapter.acce
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
        string t = ex.StackTrace;
        // throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this, because the value of the `ID` column will **only** be determined once you actually **save** the row to the database .... this **cannot** reliably be determined ahead of time, when you start inserting the data in a GUI component

Comment: @marc_s I understood you correctly that the question should look like this: How can I make an automatic substitution of IDs from the database in the dataGridView for the new record `after saving the record`?

Comment: OK, in that case: if you're using the `SqlDataAdapter` approach, you'll need to **re-load** the data set - I don't think there's any "automagic" way to just update the existing data being displayed

Comment: @marc_s Is this the best example for solving my problem? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values)    

I would not want to use this example because it is big.
But if there is no other solution, I will use

Comment: As long as you're using the `SqlDataAdapter` approach - yes, I believe that is the most efficient and easiest way to get back the `ID` values; everything else would require reloading the whole data set. If you'd be using something like Dapper and/or Entity Framework, it would be a different stories, though .....